# QTP / UFT identifying Internet Explorer_TridentDlgFrame

Tags: browser, window, qtp

I'm trying to automate a 3rd party application at work. It is (supposedly!) Web based - automation begins with launching IE. However, this produces pop up windows, which QTP identifies as class `Window` (rather than a new "Browser") - and the nativeclass is `Internet Explorer_TridentDlgFrame`. Within this window is a single Object (not a Page as per Browser windows) of class `WinObject` nativeclass `Internet Explorer_Server`.

Within this window, QTP cannot see any of the individual controls - edit boxes etc.

Has anyone had any similar experience with this TridentDlgFrame and QTP? Any advice on how to automate it?

(This is based on Win Server 2008 R2, IE8 (I know, don't ask!!!), and QTP 11)

Many thanks

Comment: What version of QTP/UFT and IE are you using? Also what version of Windows?

Comment: Hi @Motti - OP edited to include this info.

Comment: You need to license, install and enable the Web addin. Without it, you get the results you see. With it, it should work as long as you start the browser after QTP.

Comment: We have the Web addin... Sorry my OP wasn't that clear - the "main" window is correctly identified as a Browser... but when you click on a link / button within that, it produces this TridentDlgFrame pop up which isn't seen as a browser...